# error C3207: invalid template argument for 'T', class template expected

Tags: c++, c++17

I am implementing a system where i have templated setter and getter functions that either take a type and convert it to some internal representation, or return the internal representation in some user-requested type. For the below code sample, this work fine with the SetValue function, but no matching template function can be found for the get function. MSVC (16.9.0, in c++latest mode) provides the following diagnostic: `error C3207: 'GetValue': invalid template argument for 'T', class template expected`, due to which no matching overload function is found. How do i fix this?

```
#include <type_traits> 
#include <tuple>

template <template <class...> class T, class... Args>
void SetValue(T<Args...> data_);

template <template <class...> class T, class... Args>
T<Args...> GetValue();

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    auto a = std::make_tuple(2,3);
    SetValue(a);
    GetValue<std::tuple<int, int>>(); // fails
    GetValue<decltype(a)>();          // also fails
    using type = decltype(a);
    GetValue<type>();                 // also fails
}
```

I need to get the Args parameter pack for stuff I need to do in these functions and for overloading with enable_if, so i can't change the declaration to

```
template <class T>
T GetValue()
```

Note also that `std::tuple` is just an example, could be another variadic class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given template declaration `template <template <class...> class T, class... Args>`, `T` should be a class template (a.k.a. a template-template argument).

`std::tuple` is a class template, `std::tuple<int, int>` is a type.

So this is how it could be instantiated:

```
    GetValue<std::tuple, int, int>();
```